# CakePHP - Best JQuery book to learn while creating CakePHP applications

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am currently learning CakePHP and would like to integrate JQuery on several UI actions, like forms, etc.

I would like some suggestions in what is the best JQuery book to buy so I can learn and use it with CakePHP.

I have been trying to integrate different tutorials I've seen online without much success. I will need to understand JQuery first.

Thanks alot,

AS.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/ he has a few books, and is the founder of jQuery and you won't get any better :P unless you are good at looking ofcourse as for CakePHP I have no idea...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a few books in CakePHP already and I am getting pretty comfortable with it. I will check ejohn.org. Thanks again.

Comment: Although thinking about it any book, is rubbish as they are outdated by a huge factor, simply because, by the time it hits the shelves and arrives to your house and editing, and approvals and other complicated things, * [times] of publication date, you are looking at something ancient, best place to do anything with jquery it's the website, the API documentation it has examples, demos and much more [thats just my opinion though] but best of luck :) oh yeah, it could be no jquery there on johns website, but advanced javascript

Comment: Cool. I was looking thru the website and saw a lot of tutorials and examples. Thanks a lot. BTW, when I started learning CakePHP I purchased a couple of books and when they arrived and I started coding their examples, I realized that their code (1.2) was no longer compatible with the Current Version of CakePHP which is 1.3. Waste of money.

Comment: Leave the books to be read by the church attendees :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jquery i suggest - jquery in Action

For Cakephp Related jQuery - i suggest you Practical Application in CakePHP. where they show how to build mini application using cakePHP and a good amount of jQuery has been used in that.

Also if u want to improve your cakePHP skills have a look at CakePHP 1.3 cookbook.

Comment: the Practical Application in CakePHP is outdated. I already it have it. I might purse jQuery in Action

Comment: yeah.. i had read it back in the days :P but u will get the idea how to work with cake